# Fatal Exception: MAIN in Android project

Tags: android, database, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I am creating a database to store text inputs from a list. However, I am getting an error that I cannot find how to fix.

My list code:

```
package bookshelf.Android.Java;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import bookshelf.Android.Java.R;


public class Own extends Activity
{
    private EditText item;
    private ListView lv;
    private Toast toast;
    private Button addButton;
    ArrayList<String> items;
    ArrayAdapter<String> listad;
    List<String> books;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.own);
            CharSequence text = "Item added!";
            toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            setUpView();



    }
    private void setUpView()
    {
        item = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.txtAmount);
        lv = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        addButton = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.Add);
        items = new ArrayList<String>();
        items.clear();
        final DataBaseOwn dbo = new DataBaseOwn(Own.this);

        listad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);//need to create a way to get items to equal books
        lv.setAdapter(listad);
        addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                addItemList();
                books = dbo.get(items);
                toast.show();
            }
        });
        item.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
                {
                    addItemList();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
    protected void addItemList()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (isInputValid(item))
        {
            items.add(0,item.getText().toString());
            item.setText("");
            listad.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
    protected boolean isInputValid(EditText item2)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generatd method stub
        if (item2.getText().toString().trim().length()<1)
        {
            item2.setError("Please Enter Item");
            return false;
        } 
        else 
        {
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

and this is the database code:

```
package bookshelf.Android.Java;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DataBaseOwn extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    public static final int VERSION = 1;
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Own List";
    public static final String DBNAME = "ownList.sqlite";
    public static final String ID = "id"; 
    public static final String BOOK = "book";
    static SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DataBaseOwn(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        createDatabase(db);
    }
    private void createDatabase(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + ID + "integer primary key autoincrement not null" + BOOK + " text " + ");");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
    public Long Insert(String book)
    {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(BOOK, book);
        return db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    }
    public List<String> get( ArrayList<String> item)
    {
        String[] column = new String[] {BOOK};
        Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_NAME, column, null, null, null, null, null);
        List<String> result = item;
        int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(BOOK);
        for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext())
        {
            result.add(c.getString(columnIndex));
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

These are the errors I am getting before I changed my code to the first answer that was posted:

```
   10-17 03:18:42.993: D/dalvikvm(2054): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 3% free 10829K/11143K, paused 100ms
    10-17 03:18:43.056: I/dalvikvm(2054): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    10-17 03:18:43.114: I/dalvikvm(2054): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    10-17 03:18:43.523: I/dalvikvm(2054): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    10-17 03:18:43.633: I/dalvikvm(2054): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    10-17 03:18:43.723: D/gralloc_goldfish(2054): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
    10-17 03:18:44.033: I/dalvikvm(2054): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    10-17 03:18:44.093: I/dalvikvm(2054): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    10-17 03:19:26.243: D/dalvikvm(2054): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 542K, 7% free 10369K/11143K, paused 85ms
    10-17 03:19:26.293: I/dalvikvm-heap(2054): Grow heap (frag case) to 12.537MB for 2457616-byte allocation
    10-17 03:19:26.426: I/dalvikvm(2054): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    10-17 03:19:26.743: I/dalvikvm(2054): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    10-17 03:19:26.793: D/dalvikvm(2054): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2K, 6% free 12767K/13575K, paused 10ms+8ms
    10-17 03:19:26.903: I/dalvikvm(2054): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    10-17 03:19:26.963: I/dalvikvm(2054): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    10-17 03:19:27.413: I/dalvikvm(2054): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    10-17 03:19:27.483: I/dalvikvm(2054): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    10-17 03:19:27.675: D/dalvikvm(2054): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 6% free 12767K/13575K, paused 89ms
    10-17 03:19:27.773: I/dalvikvm-heap(2054): Grow heap (frag case) to 17.808MB for 5529616-byte allocation
    10-17 03:19:27.903: I/dalvikvm(2054): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    10-17 03:19:28.073: I/dalvikvm(2054): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    10-17 03:19:28.133: D/dalvikvm(2054): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 5% free 18167K/19015K, paused 9ms+11ms
    10-17 03:19:28.403: I/dalvikvm(2054): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    10-17 03:19:28.463: I/dalvikvm(2054): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    10-17 03:19:28.903: I/dalvikvm(2054): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    10-17 03:19:29.053: I/dalvikvm(2054): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    10-17 03:19:29.413: I/dalvikvm(2054): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    10-17 03:19:29.504: I/dalvikvm(2054): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    10-17 03:19:35.773: D/AndroidRuntime(2054): Shutting down VM
    10-17 03:19:35.773: W/dalvikvm(2054): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
    10-17 03:51:39.553: I/dalvikvm(2103): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'

    10-17 03:19:35.813: E/AndroidRuntime(2054): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

    10-17 03:19:35.813: E/AndroidRuntime(2054): java.lang.NullPointerException

    10-17 03:19:35.813: E/AndroidRuntime(2054):     at bookshelf.Android.Java.DataBaseOwn.get(DataBaseOwn.java:55)

    10-17 03:19:35.813: E/AndroidRuntime(2054):     at bookshelf.Android.Java.Own$1.onClick(Own.java:53)

    10-17 03:19:35.813: E/AndroidRuntime(2054):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)

    10-17 03:19:35.813: E/AndroidRuntime(2054):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)

    10-17 03:19:35.813: E/AndroidRuntime(2054):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)

    10-17 03:19:35.813: E/AndroidRuntime(2054):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

    10-17 03:19:35.813: E/AndroidRuntime(2054):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

    10-17 03:19:35.813: E/AndroidRuntime(2054):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)

    10-17 03:19:35.813: E/AndroidRuntime(2054):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

    10-17 03:19:35.813: E/AndroidRuntime(2054):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

    10-17 03:19:35.813: E/AndroidRuntime(2054):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)

    10-17 03:19:35.813: E/AndroidRuntime(2054):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)

    10-17 03:19:35.813: E/AndroidRuntime(2054):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

These are the new set of errors that I am getting after I put this line in 
db = this.getWritableDatabase();
before line 54.


10-17 04:08:45.765: E/AndroidRuntime(2151): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-17 04:08:45.765: E/AndroidRuntime(2151): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY: , while compiling: create table OwnList(idinteger primary key autoincrement not nullbook text );
10-17 04:08:45.765: E/AndroidRuntime(2151):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
10-17 04:08:45.765: E/AndroidRuntime(2151):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:68)
10-17 04:08:45.765: E/AndroidRuntime(2151):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileSql(SQLiteProgram.java:134)
10-17 04:08:45.765: E/AndroidRuntime(2151):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileAndbindAllArgs(SQLiteProgram.java:361)
10-17 04:08:45.765: E/AndroidRuntime(2151):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.acquireAndLock(SQLiteStatement.java:260)
10-17 04:08:45.765: E/AndroidRuntime(2151):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:84)
10-17 04:08:45.765: E/AndroidRuntime(2151):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1899)
10-17 04:08:45.765: E/AndroidRuntime(2151):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1839)
10-17 04:08:45.765: E/AndroidRuntime(2151):     at bookshelf.Android.Java.DataBaseOwn.createDatabase(DataBaseOwn.java:36)
10-17 04:08:45.765: E/AndroidRuntime(2151):     at bookshelf.Android.Java.DataBaseOwn.onCreate(DataBaseOwn.java:32)
10-17 04:08:45.765: E/AndroidRuntime(2151):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:165)
10-17 04:08:45.765: E/AndroidRuntime(2151):     at bookshelf.Android.Java.DataBaseOwn.get(DataBaseOwn.java:54)
10-17 04:08:45.765: E/AndroidRuntime(2151):     at bookshelf.Android.Java.Own$1.onClick(Own.java:53)
10-17 04:08:45.765: E/AndroidRuntime(2151):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
10-17 04:08:45.765: E/AndroidRuntime(2151):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
10-17 04:08:45.765: E/AndroidRuntime(2151):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
10-17 04:08:45.765: E/AndroidRuntime(2151):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-17 04:08:45.765: E/AndroidRuntime(2151):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-17 04:08:45.765: E/AndroidRuntime(2151):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
10-17 04:08:45.765: E/AndroidRuntime(2151):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-17 04:08:45.765: E/AndroidRuntime(2151):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-17 04:08:45.765: E/AndroidRuntime(2151):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-17 04:08:45.765: E/AndroidRuntime(2151):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-17 04:08:45.765: E/AndroidRuntime(2151):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm sorry that they are not formatted nicely, I do not know how to do that.

Comment: Which class are you referencing?

Comment: The DataBaseOwn class

Comment: That is the query that I created to store into.

Comment: Can you please, provide the full log, as I don't see the caused by part here in the log.

Comment: The full log has been posted.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure but can the Table name have space when you define it?

```
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Own List";
```

and could you make sure that here the items aren't returning null.

```
books = dbo.get(items);
```

**EDIT** In the *setUpView()* method, (for *addButton* in the *setOnClickListener*) after calling *addItemList*(); Could you check if the items is returning null or something else?

**EDIT 2**  use try & catch for this block - `books = dbo.get(items);`

Comment: I took the space out of the table name and it did not get rid of any errors. I'm not sure what you mean by "could you make sure that here the items aren't returning null."

Comment: I don't know how to do that. There was an answer before yours that got deleted and it got rid of the null error but more were produced and I have no idea what they mean or how to go about fixing them.

Comment: I created a try & catch block and there were no exceptions caught.

Answer (score 0):

There are some confusion on your code, although I think the following may be caused the paroblem:

You does not initialize the db with anything, so it's null. If you try to use this null to do anything, it will caused an NullPonterException.

I suggest you to follow this great tutorial:

www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-sqlite-database-with-multiple-tables/

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I did initialize the db as updated in question. It created new errors that are now listed above. I have no idea what they mean or how to fix them.

Comment: I am sorry, do you use getWritableDatabase to read data from database?
Can you please check your get method database permision?

Answer (score 0):

you are missing space between `"` and `integer` -> change to `ID + " integer...` in your `createDatabase(SQLiteDatabase db)` method